# perl6 text substitution on array

Tags: raku

I'm trying to apply a text substitution to an entire array.

However, when I try to alter the array, it shows that it only has 1 element, when it should have 26.

An example below in Perl6 REPL:

```
> my @a = 'a'..'z'
[a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z]
> my @a1 = @a.subst(/<[aeiou]>/, 1, :g)
[1 b c d 1 f g h 1 j k l m n 1 p q r s t 1 v w x y z]
> @a1.elems
1#this should be 26
> @a.elems
26
```

how can I alter an array with a text substitution across the entire array, and return an array?

also: the perl6 website is down, I can't access the many manual pages :(

Comment: Please use https://docs.perl6.wakelift.de until issues with hardware and/or DNS are solved

Comment: docs.perl6.org should be live again now.  If not, clear your DNS cache.

Comment: Some methods assume their invocant is a plural container. If it's actually singular they may coerce it to be a plural container containing that single thing. Conversely, other methods assume their invocant is a singular thing. If it's actually plural they may coerce it to a single thing. `.subst` assume its invocant is a single string. If it's actually an array it joins the array's elements into a single string with spaces between the elements. Hence the behavior you see.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By using the `>>.` hyper operator: this calls the given method on each element of the list, and creates a list of the result of the call.

```
my @a = "a".."z";
my @b = @a>>.subst(/ <[aeiou]> /, 1, :g);
dd @a, @b;

# Array @a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
# Array @b = ["1", "b", "c", "d", "1", "f", "g", "h", "1", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "1", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "1", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
```

Answer (score 7):

`.subst` is a *Str* method.

What that means is that it assumes it's first argument (the invocant) is a *Str*. If it isn't already a *Str* it gets coerced into a *Str*.

When you call `.Str` on an array, it joins all of the values together with a space as a separator.

```perl6
my @a = < a b c >;
say @a.perl;       # ["a", "b", "c"]
say @a.Str.perl;   # "a b c"
```

So these three lines are exactly equivalent:

```perl6
@a.subst(/<[aeiou]>/, 1, :g);
@a.Str.subst(/<[aeiou]>/, 1, :g);
@a.join(" ").subst(/<[aeiou]>/, 1, :g);
```

Perl6 does this because it is consistent. You always know that the output of a single call to `.subst` is a single *Str*. You also know that the invocant is treated as a *Str*.

If it did something different on arrays, it would become difficult to keep track of which methods change depending on there invocant and how they change.

We have only to look at Perl5 to see how hard it is to remember every quirk of every function when they aren't consistent.
(Try to think of all of the functions in Perl5 which operate on `$_` by default, and what they do in scalar vs. list context.)

---

Instead of calling `.subst` on the single array value, you want to call it on each of the values it contains.

There are several ways to do that:

```perl6
my @ = @a.map( *.subst(…) )

my @ = @a».subst(…)

my @ = do for @a { .subst(…) }

my @ = @a.duckmap( -> Str $_ { .subst(…) } ) # only change Str's
```

Comment: Do you recommend assigning to an anonymous array `@`, or updating `@a` with the `.=` operator, as in `@a.=map( *.subst(…) );` ? Is one favored over the other? Are there any circumstances where the `@a.=map( *.subst(…) );`  form would fail while the `@` anonymous array form would succeed? Thx!

Comment: @jubilatious1 I would recommend creating new values by default as that is likely to create problems later. Imagine you have a function that takes an array as input and modifies it in place. Now imagine that you called it with an array that you didn't want modified. And worse yet it may take you a while to even notice that happens, let alone track down where and how. (Actually I recommend returning a Sequence and letting your caller decide whether they want to keep the values as they are produced.)